# Offset of the matched string in solr

Tags: java, solr, solrj, apache-tika

I am indexing the pdf files using solr and tika. I want offset or position of the first occurence of the matched string in the pdf files which I have indexed. Basically I will search for some word and I will get the pdf file link in which the word is found and when I click that link I should be able to scroll to that page in which the word is found. How to go about it?